# What's with the Beyblade references?

Tags: komi-cant-communicate

In volume 16, *Communication 223: Culture Festival, Day 1*, I was kind of baffled to see this Beyblade reference:

[image: Komi playing Beyblade]

(Though this picture I found on Google must be a fan translation, because the actual dialogue in the official version is different, with Tadano just saying, "What the--?!", and the other dialogue bubble saying "Then they played Beyblade with the townsfolk.)

So they have this throwaway line to Beyblade in this panel, and then they don't mention it again or explain it at all. Don't get me wrong: It was hilarious and I love it. But it also left me a bit curious as to why.

I thought I remembered Beyblade being mentioned before, and a google search came up with this, which seemed familiar to my memories:

[image: First beyblade reference]

So, what's the deal with these references? Does the author just like Beyblade, or are they involved with it in some way? I tried googling to find out if there's anything to it, but all I really learned was that other people found it just as funny as I did, and maybe it's become a meme or something.

So, what's the deal? Is there anything to this? Any particular reason it's Beyblade, and not something else?

Comment: FWIW, [the original Japanese panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zv0N9.png) also mentioned *Beyblade*. Apparently, the anime director [Kazuki Kawagoe](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/people.php?id=157953) was involved in *Beyblade Burst* series, though it's still unclear what is the relationship with the anime crew to the manga, or even if there's any connection.